# Does updating a partially indexed field add or remove it from an index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, index-tuning

We can create a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html) for a field in Postgres.

I am looking at using this to stop rows which are `archived` from being in an index on a `created_at field`:

1. First we create the index:

   ```
   test=# CREATE INDEX idx_my_table_created_at ON my_table(created_at) WHERE NOT(archived);
   ```
2. We insert two rows, one which gets in `idx_my_table_created_at` and one which does not:

   ```
    id |         created_at         | archived
   ----+----------------------------+----------
     2 | 2012-10-12 17:39:17.28511  | t
     1 | 2012-10-12 17:38:55.531278 | f
   ```
3. Now we `UPDATE` a row which is presently in the index, such that it *shouldn't* be in the index:

   ```
   test=# UPDATE my_table SET archived = true WHERE id = 1;
   ```

My question: Is `id = 1` still in `idx_my_table_created_at`?

This question follows on from [an answer to a previous question I asked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25129/how-should-we-handle-rows-which-wont-be-queried-once-they-are-old-in-postgresql/25132#25132) on how to handle rows which won't be queried once they are old, hence `archived`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Note: I'm not a deep expert in the Pg guts. This is only my understanding. You should really read the [mvcc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) and [internals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/internals.html) sections of the manual)*.

Yes, initially the row with `id = 1` is still in the index, despite the index's `WHERE` clause excluding it because it has been updated with `archived = true`. At some point down the track the index entry will be purged by `VACUUM` or autovacuum, freeing the space.

The reason for this is PostgreSQL's MVCC design. Other concurrent transactions might still be able to see the old version of the row with `id = 1, archived = false` - either `READ COMMITTED` transactions with a long-running statement, or `SERIALIZABLE` transactions that don't see changes committed after they began. If the index entry were removed when the row was updated those transactions wouldn't find the row in index scans and would produce the wrong result.

Technically what's actually happening is that the old row still exists, it's just had an `xmax` set so newer transactions ignore it when they see it. After the update the index points to that row, same as before. A new row with `archived = true` has been inserted with an `xmin` above the old row's `xmax`, so any given transaction either sees the old or new version, never both. That new row is not added to the index.

Eventually there will be no open transaction that can still see the old row, so `VACUUM` will come by and remove the old row and its index entry, freeing the space for re-use.

Note that the index its self has no row visibility information. You can - and often do - have many versions of a row, each with index entries. When a transaction looks for matching index entries it reads all of the versions (unless it can tell from the visibility map that it doesn't need to) and ignores all but the one that has an `xmin` and `xmax` that makes it visible to that transaction.

This is one of many good reasons to ensure that autovaccum runs frequently. It reduces the number of dead index entries and dead rows you have lying around wasting space and I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I'm a reluctant to accept right now though, because I've put this live and am still seeing the index still grow, despite the number of `archived = false` rows remaining (essentially) constant (including after a `VACUUM`, but not a `FULL`)

Comment: @DaveTapley Thanks very much for linking to that conversation, it's useful and informative.

Comment: Here's a cleaned version of [the IRC conversation](https://raw.github.com/gist/3955433/b50e8e0bfa354a7250afb0f6335eabaac2ba806b/) referenced above.

It was from the `#postgresql` channel on the `freenode` IRC network, there are very helpful people in there! (also updated my name on here to match my IRC handle, to avoid confusion).

Comment: [Updated gist link to IRC conversation](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dukedave/3955433/raw/b50e8e0bfa354a7250afb0f6335eabaac2ba806b/gistfile1.txt)